# Comparing the results of multiple regressions of the sample sample for different year

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, stata, excel

For a period of ten years, I have to identify, if there are timely variations of impact of the independent variables on the dependent variable.

So far, I have run an RE regression for the entire period. But now I have to identify variatins over time. My approach is to run one multilinear regression for the sample for each year from 2011 to 2021. Then, I would compare the coefficients and intercepts in a scatterplot and graph to depict their varying impact over time.

Does this make sense? Thank you already for your help!

I use Stata and Excel and only have basic experience.

---

I have panel data for ten years (2001-2011), then CSR strategy score is my dependent variable and I would like to understand the impact of different independent variables on the CSR strategy score over time.

Would I then create a dummy for each year and what do the interaction coefficients tell me?

---

[image]

This is what I have done so far. But I dont know what the coefficients of the year tell me

Comment: It sounds like you have panel data, but can you clarify your data structure and specification? The easiest thing would be to add year dummies and year-x interactions to the RE model and test that the interaction coefficients are jointly zero.

Comment: Unlike forum-style discussion sites, Cross Validated 
threads do not consist of a sequence of posts forming a 
conversation between the original poster and the 
answerers. We use a Q&A style where the question is posted 
once at the top, and is updated (using the "edit" button) 
where necessary for clarification. Sometimes 
it makes sense to ask a new, follow-up question instead of 
editing the old one. 
Please don't use the "answer" space to post clarifications 
to your own questions 
- have a look at the [tour] to understand how our site 
works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where I have a dataset of 49 pigs (indexed by $i$) whose weights are observed over 9 weeks (indexed by $t$). I simulated an experiment by having some pigs put on more weight (see code below). While all pigs put on kgs over time, the yellow line looks a bit steeper:
[image]

Do the two lines really have different slopes? The RE model is

$$E[\mathtt{weight_{it}} \vert t, \mathtt{treated_i} ] = \mu + \alpha_i + \delta_t + \beta \cdot \mathtt{treated_i} + \gamma_t \cdot \mathbf{I}(\mathtt{week=t}) \cdot \mathtt{treated_i} $$

Here the effect of treatment is a function of time: $$\beta + \gamma_t$$

You can test the hypothesis that effect does not vary with time by testing the joint null that $\gamma_2,\dots,\gamma_9=0$ against the alternative that they are not zero. Since we need to drop one time dummy, the effect in week 1 is not identified. This means that $\beta = (\beta_T + \gamma_1)$ and everything will be relative to the impact in week 1.

Here's the Stata output:

```
. capture ssc install coefplot

. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. xtset id week 

Panel variable: id (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: week, 1 to 9
         Delta: 1 unit

. generate treated = mod(id,2)

. replace weight = weight*(1 + .029*week/9) if treated == 1
(216 real changes made)

. xtreg weight i.week##i.treated, re vce(cluster id)

Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs     =        432
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =         48

R-squared:                                      Obs per group:
     Within  = 0.9860                                         min =          9
     Between = 0.0358                                         avg =        9.0
     Overall = 0.9327                                         max =          9

                                                Wald chi2(17)     =    6567.80
corr(u_i, X) = 0 (assumed)                      Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

                                    (Std. err. adjusted for 48 clusters in id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      weight | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |
          2  |   6.833333   .2480495    27.55   0.000     6.347165    7.319501
          3  |   13.85417   .4551682    30.44   0.000     12.96205    14.74628
          4  |   19.47917   .4884237    39.88   0.000     18.52187    20.43646
          5  |   25.45833   .6543407    38.91   0.000     24.17585    26.74082
          6  |   31.60417   .6799763    46.48   0.000     30.27144     32.9369
          7  |   37.41667   .8166819    45.82   0.000       35.816    39.01733
          8  |   44.20833   .9016777    49.03   0.000     42.44108    45.97559
          9  |   49.85417   1.079434    46.19   0.000     47.73852    51.96982
             |
   1.treated |   .7066298   .7226836     0.98   0.328    -.7098042    2.123064
             |
week#treated |
        2 1  |  -.0211066   .3319502    -0.06   0.949    -.6717171     .629504
        3 1  |   .2761475   .6378184     0.43   0.665    -.9739536    1.526249
        4 1  |   .2849352   .6875297     0.41   0.679    -1.062598    1.632469
        5 1  |   .0804423   .9307069     0.09   0.931     -1.74371    1.904594
        6 1  |   .6581483   .9600435     0.69   0.493    -1.223502    2.539799
        7 1  |   1.376338   1.145815     1.20   0.230    -.8694176    3.622095
        8 1  |   1.860593   1.295432     1.44   0.151    -.6784076    4.399593
        9 1  |   2.806245   1.604311     1.75   0.080    -.3381472    5.950638
             |
       _cons |   24.70833   .4370002    56.54   0.000     23.85183    25.56484
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  3.9696885
     sigma_e |   2.118182
         rho |  .77838142   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store re_model

. testparm week#treated

 ( 1)  2.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 2)  3.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 3)  4.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 4)  5.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 5)  6.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 6)  7.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 7)  8.week#1.treated = 0
 ( 8)  9.week#1.treated = 0

           chi2(  8) =    8.06
         Prob > chi2 =    0.4272

. coefplot re_model, keep(*.week#1.treated) xline(0) label ///
> title("p-value = `=r(p)'*") ///
> note("*The p-value for the null that all time x treated  effects are zero again alternative that they are all not equal to zero.")
```

Here's the graph of the week x treatment interactions ($\gamma_2,\ldots,\gamma_9$):
[image]

Though there is a suggestive trend of bigger effects over time, the individual confidence intervals cover zero. Hence, none of the estimated time x treatment effects is statistically distinguishable from zero. The joint p-value that they all zero is 0.43, so we would not reject the joint null either.

The coefficients on week dummies capture the fact that pigs gain weight over time (the $\delta_t$s).

You have multiple covariates, but the idea is the same as with one. You may want to correct your inference for multiple hypothesis testing since you will be testing many parameters.